# JQuery fullCalender shows undefined on event click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

JQuery fullCalender shows undefined page while i am clicking on any event.

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
    events:{!! $get_clients !!},
    eventLimit: true,
    header: { left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) 
    {
        window.location.href = event.url;
    },   
  views: {
    timeGrid: {
      eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
    }
  } });
```

JSON
[{"title":"Palchin Agarwal","id":9,"start":"2023-11-30","end":null,"className":"bg-dark","url":"http:\www.appointments.com\edit\9"},{"title":"Ed Sheeran","id":17,"start":"2024-01-11","end":null,"className":"bg-dark","url":"http:\www.appointments.com\edit\17"}],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `url` prop contains invalid URL, replace `\` with `/`.

**Example:**

```json
[
  {
    "title":"Palchin Agarwal",
    "id":9,
    "start":"2023-11-30",
    "end":null,
    "className":"bg-dark",
    "url":"http://www.appointments.com/edit/9"
  }
]
```

Comment: same issue i changes url and its showing in footer but after click it's shows undefined

Comment: Checking the doc of FullCalendar you should not even need to set `window.location.href` as the calendar will redirect you to the `url` property out of the box. 

I am not sure what do you mean by `undefined` but when I enter `http://www.appointments.com/edit/9` into browser I get 404 Not Found error, which means such URL does not exists on the server.

Have you tried to use different url such as `https://google.com` to verify you are able to redirect to some well known, existing page?

Comment: yes i did, when i click on event it's open new window and says page not found. but if i right click on event and open in new tab it works

Comment: @إرتقاء So please check what URL it is taking you to in each case. You didn't show us any examples or screenshots, so it's difficult to help in more detail.